# Confusion regarding Harris' definition of "Quotient of variety"

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm currently studying algebraic groups and quotients of varities, I use Harris' book "Algebraic geometry" (http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/aconstant/Alg2/Bib/Harris_AlgebraicGeometry.pdf). On page 123, he first off gives a naive definition of what a quotient should be: If $G$ is an algebraic group acting on a variety $X$, then a quotient should be a variety $Y$, which points correspond one-to-one to the orbits of $X$ under the action of $G$. Furthermore, there should be a surjective morphism $\pi:X \rightarrow Y$ that is constant on orbits, so $\pi(x) = \pi(g(x))$ for all $x \in X, g \in G$. This sounds plausible to me.

Then, he says that we want to require something stronger: A quotient should be a variety $Y$ with a map $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$, that has a universal property: If $Z$ is a variety and $\varphi:X\rightarrow Z$ a regular map, then $\varphi$ factors through $\pi$ if and only if $\varphi$ is constant on orbits.

I can see then why $\pi$ must be constant on orbits, since we could just choose $Z=Y$, $\varphi = \pi$, and obviously $\pi$ factors through itself, so $\pi$ must be constant on orbits. Ok. But now I am wondering: What happened to the assumption, that $\pi$ is surjective? Does it somehow follow from this definition? I cannot see how. First I thought that surjectivity might not be needed anymore, however, two pages later he wants to show that in the case of affine varieties and finite groups, the quotient always exists. For that, he constructs a variety $Y$ and a map $\pi:X \rightarrow Y$, but then he explicitly shows that this specific map $\pi$ is indeed surjective. This confuses me.

What confuses me even more is the fact that his definition looks suspiciously similar to the definition of a categorical quotient (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_quotient), however, in the article it says that $\pi$ does not need to be surjective. Is Harris' quotient something different? I would be very grateful if someone could shed some light on my confusion.

What is also very unclear to me: On page 124 Harris gives an example, in which the quotient seemingly does not exist: He lets $G = \text{GL}_1(K) = K^*$ act on $\mathbb{A}^1$ via multiplication $(\lambda, x) \mapsto \lambda x$. This action has the two orbits, namely $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$. Using the first naive definition, we would require a regular map from $\mathbb{A}^1$ to a variety with just 2 points. But since regular maps map irreducible spaces to irreducible spaces, such a map cannot exist, since $\mathbb{A}^1$ is irreducible, but a variety with 2 points isn't. However, I don't see why a quotient could not exist in the case of the second definition. Coulnd't we just take a variety $Y$ that only contains a single point? That satisfies all the properties in the definition, right?

Edit: Or maybe I am just understanding him wrong. Maybe the second definition should be considered as a extension of the first one, and not as a completely new definition. That would make a lot more sense.